# DevExpress 16.2 XtraReport postgres null register

Tags: postgresql, devexpress, xtrareport

When using DevExpress 16.2 XtraReport, to generate a report using the postgres connector, if the row has any tupla(register) with result null, it does not load the rest of the row in the report.In version 14.2 it worked

[consulta com null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChdRq.png)

Removing the null value. Generate or report

[Query without null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX8za.png)

Comment: There are two links missing in your post

Comment: Yes, I've already corrected the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a version 3.2.1 of npgsql the error happens. Installing version 3.0.5 works